# How do I update Tkinter label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to update the Tkinter label on click of the button. Doesn't work when I click the button.

Here's the code:

```
valid = tk.StringVar()
valid.set("Not signed in")


validtext = tk.Label(root, text=valid.get(), font="Arial").grid(row=5, column=1)

testbtn_txt = tk.StringVar()
testbtn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=testbtn_txt, command=lambda:testfunc(), font="Arial", bg="#ff0000", fg="white", height=1, width=10)
testbtn_txt.set("Test")
testbtn.grid(row=3, column=1)

def testfunc():
    valid.set("Signed in")
    validtext.update()
```

What am I doing wrong? :( Thanks for help.

Comment: `text=valid.get()` retrieves the value from `valid` *at that exact moment in time*, and sets that as the text of the Label - there's no ongoing connection between the StringVar and the Label.  To do something like that, you use `textvariable=valid` instead - just like you did for the Button.

Comment: Can you give me a clue how? I am new. :( When I change that to textvariable=valid then it doesn't show "Not signed in" - instead it shows PY_VAR0.

Comment: That looks like you did `text=valid`, rather than `textvariable=`.

Comment: Please define what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @jasonharper. I changed to textvariable=valid and it worked.

The following needed changing:

```
validtext = tk.Label(root, text=valid.get(), font="Arial").grid(row=5, column=1)
```

to

```
validtext = tk.Label(root, textvariable=valid, font="Arial").grid(row=5, column=1)
```

Comment: you can remove the assignment, it is pointless

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: you can remove `validtext = `

Comment: Can you provide me with code? I'm new. :( Also, this update gave rise to a new issue. The code lines don't get executed after validtext.update().

Comment: in the given example `validtext = None`, so there is no way that removing assignment would cause issues because the only thing you later do with `validtext` is call `update` method on it which should raise an exception anyways

Comment: I'm confused...

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything is fixed!